# Question About Decrementing Numbers

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, hierarchy

My class that utilizes this [LREngine utility class](https://github.com/abhinavguptas/Salesforce-Lookup-Rollup-Summaries/blob/master/classes/LREngine.cls) aggregates numbers up a hierarchy. The problem I'm facing is that when an account is deleted the number fields are not subtracting values from the total numbers displayed on parent accounts in the hierarchy

My Class:

```
public class LAM_LRE_Rollup{

     /*
      First step is to create a context for LREngine, by specifying parent and child objects and
      lookup relationship field name
     */
    /*
          Next, one can add multiple rollup fields on the above relationship. 
          Here specify 
           1. The field to aggregate in child object
           2. The field to which aggregated value will be saved in master/parent object
           3. The aggregate operation to be done i.e. SUM, AVG, COUNT, MIN/MAX
         */

          */ 
         Sobject[] masters = LREngine.rollUp(ctx, lstAccts);    


         // Push the changes in master

         update masters;
      }
}
```

My Trigger:

```
   /*List<Account> acc = new List<Account>([SELECT Id, ParentId FROM Account WHERE id IN:Trigger.newMap.keySet()]);
       for (Account a : trigger.new) {
        if (Trigger.isUpdate && a.ParentId != Trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id).ParentId ){
            LAM_LRE_Rollup.rollupData(trigger.new);

    }
*/


}
```

Comment: N.B. I believe LRE is included inside of DLRS which is the preferred solution for rollup summaries cross lookup relationships

Comment: Are you posting under [multiple accounts](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/254701/picklist-toggle)? If so, please use the Contact link at the bottom of the page to have Stack Exchange merge them.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call your logic on `delete` and `undelete`trigger.

```
trigger LAM_DataRollup on Account (after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {

    if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate || trigger.isUndelete)
    {
        LAM_LRE_Rollup.rollupData(trigger.new);
        system.debug('db');

    }
    if(Trigger.isDelete){
         LAM_LRE_Rollup.rollupData(trigger.old);
            system.debug('db');
    }

}
```

Src : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've added this exact logic previously and it did not resolve the issue

Comment: Whats the code of `LREngine` , does it do SOQL inside?4

Comment: the code for the LREngine is too large to post here but it does do SOQL

Comment: Without looking at code, I dont think anyone can help. But if the code is called in trigger in this manner, it should work. I have a similar implementation and it works,

Comment: Ive updated the question with the LREnging